# Gerrit rule Prolog example 13 modification to score with at least one +2

Tags: gerrit

I want to change gerrit rules to be '1+2=3 Code-Review' (change are good when code review score 3 and there is at least one +2) and '+1 Verify'. Based on 
[Gerrit Code Review - Prolog Submit Rules Cookbook](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/prolog-cookbook.html#_example_13_1_1_2_code_review) example 13 (with modification from [Rule 1+1=2 from Documentation does not work](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=2469)) I was able to make +1+1+1=3. How can I apply 'at least one +2' to my code? I tried:

```
sum_list([], 0).
sum_list([H | Rest], Sum) :- sum_list(Rest,Tmp), Sum is H + Tmp.

first_list([], _).
first_list([F], F).
first_list([F | Rest], F).

score(Category, Score, User) :-
  gerrit:commit_label(label(Category, Score), User).

add_category_min_score(In, Category, Min,  P) :-
  findall(Score, score(Category, Score, User), Scores),
  findall(User, score(Category, Score, User), Users),
  sum_list(Scores, Sum),
  Sum >= Min, !,
  first_list(Users, FirstUser),
  P = [label(Category, ok(FirstUser)) | In].

add_category_min_score(In, Category, Min, P) :-
  P = [label(Category, need(Min)) | In].

add_category_score_two_req(S1, S2) :-
  gerrit:commit_label(label('Code-Review', 2), S2),

submit_rule(S) :-
  gerrit:default_submit(X),
  X =.. [submit | Ls],
  add_category_score_two_req(Ls, R),
  gerrit:remove_label(R, label('Code-Review', _), NoCR),
  add_category_min_score(NoCR, 'Code-Review', 3, Labels),
  S =.. [submit | Labels].
```

but that deletes all labels.

Comment: Did you find solution on this as i'm looking similar solution.

Comment: No, I did not found solution.